# Using SED to derive the values from a String

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

I want to use  `echo "123|456|789" | sed  's/^\(.*|\)\(.*|\).*$/\1'`

I am trying to break the string and get the individual values (without the pipe |).

- Scenario 1:  I want to get `123`
- Scenario 2:  I want to get `456`
- Scenario 3:  I want to get `789`
- Scenario 4:  I want to get `123 456 789`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you show the input, expected output and the options you have tried? There are a lot of people here who can answer this question, but you need to prove you've tried some options before posting a question here.

Comment: are you missing a '/g' at the end, like in `echo "123|456|789" | sed  's/^\(.*|\)\(.*|\).*$/\1/g'` ?

Comment: We can't answer your question without knowing what you're trying to accomplish here and what your expected results are.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not sure what you want this to do, I will confine my answer to fixing the command. It should be:

echo "123|456|789" | sed 's/^(.*|)(.*|).*$/\1/'

(note the / immediately before the last quote character).

This then gives the output:

123|

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

1. `echo '123|456|789' | sed 's/|.*//'`
2. `echo '123|456|789' | sed 's/^[0-9]*|//;s/|.*//'`
3. `echo '123|456|789' | sed 's/.*|//'`
4. `echo '123|456|789' | sed 's/|/ /g'`

Or if you're not precious about using `sed`

1. `echo '123|456|789' | cut -f1 -d\|`
2. `echo '123|456|789' | cut -f2 -d\|`
3. `echo '123|456|789' | cut -f3 -d\|`
4. `echo '123|456|789' | cut -f1,2,3 --output-delimiter=" " -d\|`

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer just fixed an error. Here is the way I would actually solve it:

Scenario 4 is the most complicated, so here is the solution:

```
echo '123|456|789' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)|\([0-9]*\)|\([0-9]*\)/\1 \2 \3/'
```

The \1, \2 and \3 at the end select the part matched between the 'decorated brackets' ( the \( and \) ). Each set of those is referenced by the next number, so \1 for the first one, etc.

For scenarios 1, 2 and 3, you could simplify that, but its easier just to cut and paste, and then just have \1, \2 or \3 as required between the last set of //. It won't hurt to leave the rest of the decorated brackets in there.

This solution can be expanded to any number of fields, although I'd probably rather use cut if possible.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed you can capture your fields by mentioning their number in shell var `$n`

```
n=2; # to get field number 2
echo "123|456|789" | sed -n "s/|/\n/$n;s/^[^\n]*|//;P"
```

while for scenario-4 is:

```
echo ... | sed -e 'y/|/ /'
```